# Token Content Access blocks access for author too

Tags: 7

I use the [Token Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/tca) module to hide member created nodes from public view and allow them  to share private links with private links (URL tokens). My problem is when a user restricts access to individual nodes using URL tokens, he cannot access them without the token either!

Answer (score 0):

I briefly looked at the module. I think you will need to make some serious code changes, I could not find an easy tweak.